# How to combine arrays that have the same value?

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like this :

```
   $arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'LOCATION DETAIL',
        'hotel_description' => '7 kms to city centre 2 kms to the airport 60 kms to the airport 6 km to the nearest station ',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'ROOMS',
        'hotel_description' => 'Rooms with elegant set up viewing our beautiful natural landscape garden, private balcony'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title=> 'RESTAURANT',
        'hotel_description' => 'The Restaurant serving Western cuisines to cater your appetite and open for 24 hours'
    ),
);
```

I want to combine arrays that have the same value. So the result of print_r is like this :

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [hotel_code] => PHCEB_00001
    [hotel_name] => Cebu Hotel
    [address] => Cebu Address
    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hotel_title] => LOCATION DETAIL
                    [hotel_description] => 7 kms to city centre 2 kms to the airport 60 kms to the airport 6 km to the nearest station
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hotel_title] => ROOMS
                    [hotel_description] => Rooms with elegant set up viewing our beautiful natural landscape garden, private balcony
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [hotel_title] => RESTAURANT
                    [hotel_description] => The Restaurant serving Western cuisines to cater your appetite and open for 24 hours
                )

        )

)
```

I had try to solve my problem, but I'm still confused

I can only make code like this :

```
$tmp = array();

    foreach($arr as $arg)
    {

        $tmp['description'][]['hotel_description'] = $arg['hotel_description'];
    }
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: *what* have you tried? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ChrisKitching, I had try it, but I'm still confused

Comment: those arrays should be combined if they coincide in four fields `id`,`hotel_code`,`hotel_name`, `address`, right ?

Comment: You did not post _what_ you tried before. Code? See [ask], and [mcve]

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Yes

Answer (score 0):

I have complicated your initial array a bit to show a complex situation when there are "*hotels*" with different "**id**" field in random order.
Solution with `uasort`, `array_reduce` and `array_diff` functions:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'LOCATION DETAIL',
        'hotel_description' => '7 kms to city centre 2 kms to the airport 60 kms to the airport 6 km to the nearest station ',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'test',
        'hotel_description' => 'Test'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title'=> 'RESTAURANT',
        'hotel_description' => 'The Restaurant serving Western cuisines to cater your appetite and open for 24 hours'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'ROOMS',
        'hotel_description' => 'Rooms with elegant set up viewing our beautiful natural landscape garden, private balcony'
    ),
);

/********** Solution ***********/
uasort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return ($a['id'] < $b['id'])? -1 : (($a['id'] > $b['id'])? 1 : 0);        
});

$result = [];
array_reduce($arr, function($prev, $item) use (&$result){    
    if( empty(array_diff([$prev['id'], $prev['hotel_code'], $prev['hotel_name'], $prev['address']], [$item['id'], $item['hotel_code'], $item['hotel_name'], $item['address']])) ){
        if (!isset($result[$prev['id']])){
            $result[$prev['id']] = [
            'id' => $prev['id'], 
            'hotel_code' => $prev['hotel_code'],
            'hotel_name' => $prev['hotel_name'],
            'address' => $prev['address'],
            'description' => [
                ['hotel_title' => $prev['hotel_title'], 'hotel_description' => $prev['hotel_description']],
                ['hotel_title' => $item['hotel_title'], 'hotel_description' => $item['hotel_description']],
            ]
            ];
        } else {
            $result[$prev['id']]['description'][] = ['hotel_title' => $item['hotel_title'], 'hotel_description' => $item['hotel_description']];
        }            
    }
    return $item;        
});
/*********************/

var_dump($result);
// the output:   

 array (size=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 1
      'hotel_code' => string 'PHCEB_00001' (length=11)
      'hotel_name' => string 'Cebu Hotel' (length=10)
      'address' => string 'Cebu Address' (length=12)
      'description' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'hotel_title' => string 'RESTAURANT' (length=10)
              'hotel_description' => string 'The Restaurant serving Western cuisines to cater your appetite and open for 24 hours' (length=84)
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              'hotel_title' => string 'LOCATION DETAIL' (length=15)
              'hotel_description' => string '7 kms to city centre 2 kms to the airport 60 kms to the airport 6 km to the nearest station ' (length=92)
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              'hotel_title' => string 'ROOMS' (length=5)
              'hotel_description' => string 'Rooms with elegant set up viewing our beautiful natural landscape garden, private balcony' (length=89)
```

Comment: The code so complex. I did not think really complex code. What there is no other way that is easier to understand?

Comment: it's complex because it should combine only those nested arrays which coincide with four distinct fields. It can be simpler if your condition would be to combine arrays by only "id" field equality

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517387/how-to-multiply-number-until-achieve-single-digit-numbers-and-counting-the-numbe

Comment: @samueltoh, I've seen that link(question) where you have accepted some answer, so what?

Comment: I had to get an answer. Thank you

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521602/how-to-make-triangle-roll-up-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this : its easy and working...

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'LOCATION DETAIL',
        'hotel_description' => '7 kms to city centre 2 kms to the airport 60 kms to the airport 6 km to the nearest station ',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'ROOMS',
        'hotel_description' => 'Rooms with elegant set up viewing our beautiful natural landscape garden, private balcony'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'hotel_code' => 'PHCEB_00001',
        'hotel_name' => 'Cebu Hotel',
        'address' => 'Cebu Address',
        'hotel_title' => 'RESTAURANT',
        'hotel_description' => 'The Restaurant serving Western cuisines to cater your appetite and open for 24 hours'
    )
);

$intersect = array_intersect($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]);
$intersectkeys = array_keys($intersect);

foreach ($arr as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if(in_array($key2, $intersectkeys)){            
            unset($arr[$key1][$key2]);
        }
    }
}
$newarr['description'] = $arr;
$result = array_merge($intersect, $newarr);
echo "<pre>".print_r($result,1)."</pre>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [hotel_code] => PHCEB_00001
    [hotel_name] => Cebu Hotel
    [address] => Cebu Address
    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [hotel_title] => LOCATION DETAIL
                    [hotel_description] => 7 kms to city centre 2 kms to the airport 60 kms to the airport 6 km to the nearest station 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hotel_title] => ROOMS
                    [hotel_description] => Rooms with elegant set up viewing our beautiful natural landscape garden, private balcony
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [hotel_title] => RESTAURANT
                    [hotel_description] => The Restaurant serving Western cuisines to cater your appetite and open for 24 hours
                )

        )

)
```